# Page option dropdown is not visible in angular-material table

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I have `angular material data table` where I have added the `items per page` option but the drop down is not coming at all. I am explaining my code below.

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">

          <!-- Position Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="hide-arrow"> Date </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
          </ng-container>
      
          <!-- Name Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
      
          <!-- Weight Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="download">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Download </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
              <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Log</a> |
              <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Data report</a> |
              <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">HTML report</a>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
      
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
      
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                       showFirstLastButtons 
                       aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
        </mat-paginator>
```

The `typescript` code is given below.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['date', 'name', 'download'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: String;
  weight: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
  {position: '2021-09-02', name: 'Test report', weight: 1.0079 },
];
```

Here the table is coming as expected like below.

[image]

But in `items per page` drop down is not opening at all where I need to display the drop down when user will click on arrow icon. Is there anybody who can help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Unable to reproduce it, Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hp6r3x?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts

Comment: Perhaps your local css might be affecting the dropdown's behaviour

Comment: @Vikas, I am expecting same but is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I removed this line from my style.css

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
```